# wp_query not returning results on tax_query

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

Here is code to start the question

```
function myfunction(){
    global $wpdb;

    $search_string = urldecode($_REQUEST['s']);

    var_dump(get_term_by('name',$search_string , 'gift_tag' )); //This fine the Query by name just fine. 

    $args =array('post_type' => 'gift',
                'posts_per_page'=> 14,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'paged'=>$p,
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'meta_key'=>'popularity',
                'order' => (isset($_REQUEST['order'])?$_REQUEST['order']:'ASC')
        );
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'gift_tag',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => $search_string
            );

    $q= new WP_Query($args);
    var_dump($q->request);  //This returns no Results, as it include 0=1 in place of tax query. 
}
```

the above function expect Query String parameter `s` in `Hebrew` `gift_tag` name and when I use that in `get_term_by` function it found the Terms just fine, but when use same name in `tax query` it doesn't find the said taxonomy and hence adding `1=0` wordpress' famous way of ignoring all results.

The behavior is restricted to terms that include `'` Hebrew characters for any word that doesn't contain that single quote mark in hebrew or english returns results perfectly.

too me, it looks like that it is some sort of bug in Wordpress that is failing to properly filter character in WP_Query.

Any idea what else might be wrong in above code.

Comment: Do not use the `name` parameter in the `tax_query`. The name of the term is wrongly sanitized in the `WP_Tax_Query` class. Because of that, the sanitized name returns no term as the sanitized name does not exists. Use `get_term_by` to get the term ID from the name and then use the ID (or even the slug) in your `tax_query`

Comment: Your suggestion is valid, however are you guessing that "name of the term is wrongly sanitized" or is there any bug submitted/known issue it is? I will follow your suggest meanwhile :).

Comment: Well sorry asking about guessing thing. I just want to be sure that my thinking match your. I had a feeling about this been the case, just want to be double sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Found my original post, everything is in there, test, bug report, etc ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggested solution is working fine for me :).

Comment: my pleasure, enjoy ;-)